# Regular expression, alphanumeric, few special character and no others

Tags: php, regex

First of all pardon me with my English grammar. Anyway, I am trying to create a regular expression which contains alpha numeric characters including spaces, comma, full stop, exclamation point and question mark, but other characters and symbols are not allowed.

Would this regular expression work?

```
'/[^a-zA-Z\s,!?]$'
```

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: When you tried it - did it work?

Comment: instead of asking it directly, give it a try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/). Use javascript's .test() method for the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.,!?]*$/`

Comment: Hei, thx a lot, it is working, one quick question though... what is the * for, i read what it is for but i can't quite get it though.

Comment: * means zero, one or more occurrences of symbols belonging to that class